# NullPointerException - JSON, Volley, NetworkImage

Tags: android, json, android-layout, android-activity, android-volley

While trying to load the following activity, I ran into a NullPoint exception, I tried resolving the issue but my attempts have been unsuccessful.

In brief, there are two activities- one that populates a list of arrays and upon click of an item in the arrays list takes the user to a second activity page (this one) that populate more information about that item. The first activity load fine with no errors shown, and were the list of array with background image is shown. I receive the unexpected error when an item on the list of arrays is clicked, and hence taking the user to the second activity.

Below is the log cat message:

```
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 1247
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.volley.Request.<init>(Request.java:130)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageRequest.<init>(ImageRequest.java:71)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.get(ImageLoader.java:220)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.get(ImageLoader.java:171)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView.loadImageIfNecessary(NetworkImageView.java:140)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView.onLayout(NetworkImageView.java:180)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1660)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.onLayout(HorizontalScrollView.java:1474)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Below is activity code that populates the list of arrays and make reference to the single item activity

```
public class CasualEventsActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String URL_WEB_SERVICE = "http://dooba.ca/analytics/casual.php";
    private GridView gv;
    private ArrayList<Events_List> container;
     private ArrayList<Events_List> items;
    public Uri list_item_bac;
    public String list_item_name;
    public String list_item_description;
    public String list_item_location;
    public String single_list_item_description;
    public String list_item_price;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.events_list_layout);
        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        container = new ArrayList<Events_List>();
        //download JSON
        listDownload();


        GridView s = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        s.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CasualEventsActivity.this,CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("list_item_name", container.get(position).getList_item_title());
                intent.putExtra("list_item_location", container.get(position).getList_item_location());
                intent.putExtra("single_list_item_description", container.get(position).getSingle_list_item_description());
                intent.putExtra("list_item_bac", container.get(position).getList_item_bac());

                startActivity(intent); //start Activity
            }
        });
    }
    public void listDownload(){
        RequestQueue volley = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest json = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, URL_WEB_SERVICE, null, ResponseListener(), ErrorListener());
        volley.add(json);
    }

    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> ResponseListener() {
        return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    //your JSON Array
                    JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("list_item");
                    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                        container.add(convertirAnuncio(array.getJSONObject(i)));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                gv.setAdapter(new AdapterEvents(getApplicationContext(),container));
                }
            };
        };


    private Response.ErrorListener ErrorListener() {
        return new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { }
        };
    }

    //object JSON
    private final Events_List convertirAnuncio(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
        long id = obj.getLong("id"); //id 
        String list_item_name = obj.getString("list_item_name"); 
        String list_item_location = obj.getString("list_item_location"); 
        String list_item_description = obj.getString("list_item_description");
        String single_list_item_description = obj.getString("single_list_item_description");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(obj.getString("list_item_bac"));
        return new Events_List(id, list_item_location, single_list_item_description,list_item_name,list_item_description,list_item_price, uri, list_item_bac);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);



        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.pageExperience:
                openPageExperience();
                return true;
            case R.id.pageMessaging:
                openPageMessage();
                return true;

            case R.id.pageEventsBooking:
                openPageBook();
                return true;

            case R.id.pageProfile:
                openPageProfile();
                return true;

            case R.id.pageReport:
                openPageReport();
                return true;

            case R.id.pageAbout:
                openPageAbout();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void openPageAbout() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void openPageReport() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void openPageProfile() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProfileChange.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    private void openPageBook() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void openPageMessage() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void openPageExperience() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MoodActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Single item activity code (where the nullpoint error is found)

```
public class CasualEventsSingleItemActivity extends Activity {

    // Declare Variables
    String list_item_name;
    String list_item_description;
    String list_item_bac;

    String list_item_price;
    String list_item_location;

    String single_list_item_description;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events_single_item);


        ImageLoader mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(Volley.newRequestQueue(this),
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
            private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                    cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return cache.get(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                cache.put(url, bitmap);
            }
        });


        Intent i = getIntent();
        list_item_name = i.getStringExtra("list_item_name");
        list_item_location = i.getStringExtra("list_item_location");
        list_item_bac = i.getStringExtra("list_item_bac");



        single_list_item_description = i.getStringExtra("single_list_item_description");

        TextView txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView txtlocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
        TextView txtsdescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sdescription);


        NetworkImageView hsvimage1 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage1);
        NetworkImageView hsvimage2 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage2);
        NetworkImageView hsvimage3 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage3);

        // Get image URLs from your previous network request...
        // I could not determine where this is stored from code in your question.
        String url1 = list_item_bac;   // e.g. http://example.com/images/image1.png
        String url2 = list_item_bac;
        String url3 = list_item_bac;

        // Set the URL of the image that should be loaded into this view, and
        // specify the ImageLoader that will be used to make the request.
        hsvimage1.setImageUrl(url1, mImageLoader);
        hsvimage2.setImageUrl(url2, mImageLoader);
        hsvimage3.setImageUrl(url3, mImageLoader);

        // Set results to the TextViews
        txtname.setText(list_item_name);
        txtlocation.setText(list_item_location);
        txtsdescription.setText(single_list_item_description);


        Button mConfirm2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bConfirm2);
        mConfirm2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

               // Create the class and the columns
                currentUser.saveInBackground();

                currentUser.put("ActivityName", list_item_name); 
                currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                        if (e == null) {
                            // Success!
                            Intent intent = new Intent(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this, usermatch.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                   }
               });
                //CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this, MatchingActivity.class));
            }
        });




    }
    }
```

Layout code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_bac3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:alpha="0.9"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="3"
        android:shadowDy="3"
        android:shadowRadius="0.01"
        android:textColor="#82CAFF"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="3"
        android:shadowDy="3"
        android:shadowRadius="0.01"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dividertop"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/location"
        android:alpha="0.6"
        android:background="@drawable/divider11"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dividerbottom"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vsvdescription"
       android:alpha="0.6"
        android:background="@drawable/divider11"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_head"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/isgallery"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dividerbottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
         >

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

               <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/hsvimage1"
                android:layout_width="148dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:padding="1dp" />
               <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/hsvimage2"
                android:layout_width="148dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:padding="1dp" />
               <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/hsvimage3"
                android:layout_width="148dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#CCC"
                android:padding="1dp" />
               <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/hsvimage4"
                android:layout_width="148dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:padding="1dp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                  </HorizontalScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bConfirm2"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/isgallery"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_bac"
        android:text="Confirm"
        android:textColor="#2B3856"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

     <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/vsvdescription"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp" 
        android:padding="5dp"       

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dividertop"
         >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sdescription"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:alpha="0.65"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance, and if you need any clarification, let me know.
All the best,

Update 2

In the activity that populates the list of arrays, the item being populated on the single item activity (after user has click on an item) is referred to as

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CasualEventsActivity.this,CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("list_item_name", container.get(position).getList_item_title());
            intent.putExtra("list_item_location", container.get(position).getList_item_location());
            intent.putExtra("single_list_item_description", container.get(position).getSingle_list_item_description());
            intent.putExtra("list_item_bac", container.get(position).getList_item_bac());
            startActivity(intent); //start Activity
        }
```

The get item reference is refered in another activity

```
public class Events_List {
public long id;
public String list_item_title;
public String list_item_location;
public String list_item_price;
public Uri single_list_item_bac;
public Uri list_item_bac;

public String list_item_description;
public String single_list_item_description;

public Uri url;

public Events_List(long id, String list_item_location, String single_list_item_description, String list_item_title, String list_item_description, String list_item_price, Uri url, Uri list_item_bac){
    this.id = id;
    this.list_item_title = list_item_title;
    this.list_item_location = list_item_location;
    this.list_item_description = list_item_description;
    this.single_list_item_description = single_list_item_description;
    this.list_item_price = list_item_price;
    this.list_item_bac = list_item_bac;
    this.url = url;
}

public String getList_item_title()
{
    return this.list_item_title;
}

public String getList_item_bac()
{
    return this.list_item_title;
}

public String getList_item_location()
{
    return this.list_item_location;
}

public String getList_item_price()
{
    return this.list_item_price;
}

public String getList_item_description()
{
    return this.list_item_description;
}

public String getSingle_list_item_description()
{
    return this.single_list_item_description;
}


}
```

Update 3:

```
08-31 12:20:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1271): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-31 12:20:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1271): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 1271
08-31 12:20:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1271): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-31 12:20:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at com.dooba.beta.Events_List.getList_item_bac(Events_List.java:36)
08-31 12:20:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at com.dooba.beta.CasualEventsActivity$1.onItemClick(CasualEventsActivity.java:71)
08-31 12:20:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
08-31 12:20:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
08-31 12:20:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
08-31 12:20:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
08-31 12:20:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-31 12:20:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-31 12:20:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-31 12:20:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-31 12:20:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-31 12:20:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-31 12:20:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-31 12:20:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-31 12:20:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can see `list_item_bac` by browser ?

Comment: Thanks for asking. This is how list_item_bac is displayed in browser using JSON - ,"list_item_bac":"http:\/\/www.dinemagazine.ca\/wp-content\/uploads\/2012\/09\/labitoir3.jpg" and written in PHP as    "list_item_bac" => "http://farm1.staticflickr.com/80/252172423_2842685012.jpg"

Comment: but it gives me`The requested URL /wp-content/uploads/2012/09/lâ€Œâ€‹abitoir3.jpg was not found on this server.` anyway do you use uri ? do you cast it to string correctly?

Comment: oh sorry I gave you the wrong link. its actually   "list_item_bac" => "http://theflyingpigvan.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/post/galleries/705/FP_I2A02470-use-1024x682.jpg",
I included an update 2 under my initial post to give you with a better understanding.

Comment: `return this.list_item_title;` to  `return this.list_item_title.toString();`

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will package the file and send it to you.

Comment: i expect that your test project can be run i mean it has all necessary codes that can do something

Comment: i import your project but i can not get above error because i think there is some damage in it,`08-31 17:15:25.825: E/AndroidRuntime(3577): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.dooba.beta.projecttest" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.dooba.beta-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.dooba.beta-2, /system/lib]]
` could you solve it? i think you can solve it because you know how to split it, try solve that and tell me what to do. after that i will try to solve your volley error ;-)

Comment: try work on what you upload to get volley error then tell me what to do.

Comment: any problem ? tell me !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
public String getList_item_bac()
{
    return this.list_item_bac.toString();
}
```

to

```
public Uri getList_item_bac()
{
    return this.list_item_bac;
}
```

also i have changed this

```
   private final Events_List convertirAnuncio(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
    long id = obj.getLong("id"); //id 
    String list_item_name = obj.getString("list_item_name"); 
    String list_item_location = obj.getString("list_item_location"); 
    String list_item_description = obj.getString("list_item_description");
    String single_list_item_description = obj.getString("single_list_item_description");
    String list_item_price = obj.getString("list_item_price");
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(obj.getString("list_item_bac"));
    return new Events_List(id, list_item_location, single_list_item_description,list_item_name,list_item_description,list_item_price, uri, uri);
}
```

and change

```
intent.putExtra("list_item_bac", container.get(position).getList_item_bac());
```

to

```
intent.putExtra("list_item_bac", container.get(position).getList_item_bac().toString());
```

so you will get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks brother, you have been an incredible help. This has resolved my issue.